# Inline CSS style block with React

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

Does anyone know of a way to write an inline style block inside of react like so:

```
return (
   <style>
      p { 
         color: red
      }
   </style>
)
```

Comment: check this out (https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example would be transformed to this:

```
    return (
        <p style={{color: 'red'}}>Your text</p>
    )
```